# Multiple instances Elmedia Player mac

Tags: mac, script

For opening several windows of VLC I have a script like this:

```
on run
    do shell script "open -n /Applications/VLC.app"
end run

on open theFiles
    repeat with theFile in theFiles
        do shell script "open -na /Applications/VLC.app " & quote & (POSIX path of theFile) & quote
    end repeat
end open
```

It works. Now I want to do the same thing for Elmedia Player, but because of the space in Elmedia Player it does not work.

I have tried like this:

"open -n /Applications/Elmedia\ Player.app"

But then it says "Syntax Error Expected """ but found unknown token" when I try to save it.

Help please! :)

Answer (score 0):

escape it with ' ' as below
on run
    do shell script "open -n /Applications/'Elmedia Player.app' "
    tell application "Elmedia Player" to activate
end run

Answer (score 0):

Some idiosyncratic ' shenanigans required to escape the space:

```
on run
    do shell script "open -n /Applications/Elmedia' 'Player.app"
end run
```

Comment: What does "some ' bs" mean? Remember this is a professional website.

Comment: Thank you - apologies - rephrased.

Comment: Unusual, that one.